# Como convertir sentencia SQL en Doctrine ORM

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

Habré metido unas 10 horas con algo que a nivel de consulta simple de sql me parece simple y no soy capaz de hacer con Doctrine ORM.

```
SELECT buoys_files.id, 
       buoys_files.date_start, 
       buoys_files.date_end, 
       buoys_files.filename,  files_categories.category,
            (SELECT buoys_files_users.downloads FROM buoys_files_users 
WHERE buoys_files_users.buoys_files_id = buoys_files.id 
AND buoys_files_users.user_id = '.$userId.') AS numDownloads
FROM buoys_files, files_categories 
WHERE files_categories.id = buoys_files.files_categories_id
```

Algun alma caritativa  podría enseñarme como se hace esto con las entidads y el ORM?

Mil gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('BuoysFiles')
    ->select('BuoysFiles.id, BuoysFiles.filename, BuoysFiles.date_start, BuoysFiles.date_end, files_categories.category')
    ->leftJoin('BuoysFiles.files_categories', 'files_categories')
    ->addSelect('(SELECT bfu.downloads FROM App\Entity\BuoysFilesUsers bfu WHERE bfu.buoys_files = BuoysFiles.id AND bfu.user = :user_id) AS numDownloads')
   ->setParameter('user_id', $user)
    ->getQuery();
```